# Is constantly calling cv2.VideoCapture(link, 0) creating new objects in memory?

Tags: opencv

I have an application that from time to time crashes. This app is connected to an AXIS camera. The goal of the app is to capture frames, process them for object detection and send the results to a server.
Here is the thing after a random period of time there is a RTSP session timeout. After some digging, it came to my mind that the cv2.VideoCapture might be the problem. I never release the object. Since the app needs to constantly capture frames I'm constantly calling the following command:

image = cv2.VideoCapture(link, 0)

where "link" is the ip address of the camera in RTSP protocol.
So I have the following question: what are the chances that the cv2.Videocapture(link,0) is creating in background several objects that that are having conflicts with each other and the camera drops the connection? I don't use image.read() because the frames are in a buffer and the processing is done on past frames instead of the instantaneous frame.

Comment: **absolutely do not** open, read a frame, and close the same source in a loop. that's insane resource waste. keep it open, read from the same object. -- question requires a [mre]. please also review [ask]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz hi, months ago I tried to use read function to get frames. However I noticed that some frames processed with the object detection algorithm were old, not corresponding to the latest frame from the camera. It was like if there was a buffer. Just referring that the camera needs to turn a certain amount of degrees before each processing. Also the goal of the app is not keep processing in real time. The goal is just to capture a frame, process it and send it to server side. There is only one frame to be processed for each position

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ -- never ever try to *throttle* the video coming from a camera. it's always the same issue. people think the camera makes pictures when _they_ want. doesn't work like that. it makes pictures at its own pace and you have to read them quickly, because there's a buffer and it'll fill up, causing visible latency. this is usually solved by using a thread, reading all frames, discarding those you don't have the time to process.